# Python output from print(print(print('aaa')))

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't quite understand output received from:

> print(print(print('aaa')))
>
> aaa
>
> None
>
> None

First aaa is clear. But I thought that second print(aaa) will throw an error as variable aaa is not defined...

Comment: It would be printing the return value of `print` which is `None‘.

Comment: 'aaa' is not a variable, it is a string literal.

Answer (score 7):

> print(print('aaa'))

The outer `print` will receive as argument not what inner `print` printed to stdout, but what inner `print` returned. And `print` function never returns anything (equivalent to returning `None`). That's why you see this output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which does the same thing, and you will understand it better:

```
def f():
    print('Hello')
print(f())
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
None
```

`None` is at the end because you are basically doing `print(print('Hello'))`, `print` writes something in the python interpreter and also when you do `type(print())` it outputs: `<class 'NoneType'>` So this part is `print(None)`.

So that's why the output of `print(print(print('aaa')))` includes `None`'s

Answer (score 1):

`print` prints on the standard output and returns `None`. Your second `print` statement gets result of first `print` which is `None`

Comment: Thanks! I thought that print returns the value that is printed to stdout but it's not. Now it's clear to me

Answer (score 1):

First we just split our code

```
>>>a = print('aaa')
aaa
>>>b = print(a)
None
>>>print(b)
None
```

Now you understand !!
(python 3)

Answer (score 1):

In python, when a function returns nothing explicitly, it returns `None`.

A function like `print` does an action but is not supposed to return anything, so it returns None. The print function could be something like this:

```
import sys


def print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
    for arg in args:
        file.write(str(arg))
        if arg is not args[-1]:
            file.write(str(sep))
    file.write(str(end))
    if flush:
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False):
    # The same code
    return None
```

And in both cases you will get

```
>>> print('Hello world')
Hello world
>>> print(print('Hello world'))
Hello world
None
```

Hope this helps.