# Why "NONE" appears in my output

Tags: python

This is the code and I want to know why "None" appears in my output:

```
print ("DIVISOR DE NUMEROS")

dividendo = int(input(print("Escriba el dividendo:",end="")))
divisor = int(input(print("Escriba el divisor: ",end="")))

while divisor ==0 :
    print ("¡DIVISOR DEBE SER DIFERENTE DE CERO¡")
    divisor = int(input(print("Escriba el divisor:",end="")))

cociente = dividendo // divisor
resto = dividendo % divisor

if resto == 0 :
    print ("La division es exacta. Cociente:"+str(cociente))
else :
    print ("La division no es exacta Cociente:"+str(cociente)+"Resto:"+str(resto))
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
print ("DIVISOR DE NUMEROS")

dividendo = int(input("Escriba el dividendo:",end=""))
divisor = int(input("Escriba el divisor: ",end=""))

while divisor ==0 :
    print ("¡DIVISOR DEBE SER DIFERENTE DE CERO¡")
    divisor = int(input("Escriba el divisor:",end=""))

cociente = dividendo // divisor
resto = dividendo % divisor

if resto == 0 :
    print ("La division es exacta. Cociente:"+str(cociente))
else :
    print ("La division no es exacta.     Cociente:"+str(cociente)+"Resto:"+str(resto))
```

Your code prints extra `None` because you're doing `int(input(print(...)))` it should be just `int(input(...))` because `type(print())` return `<class 'NoneType'>`

This could help: [Python output from print(print(print('aaa')))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000516/python-output-from-printprintprintaaa/51000620#51000620)